# Подсчет количества вхождений символов

Tags: perl

Изучаю для себя первый язык - Perl. Есть задание  :"Написать скрипт, которому на вход по ключу -file передается путь к текстовому файлу, он выводит на экран список букв в порядке убывания их частоты появления в тексте." У меня возникли проблемы после того,как я считал текст в массив,потом при помощи split разделил его посимвольно. Как при помощи foreach подсчитать кол-во вхождений символов( понимаю,что там должно быть что-то вроде ++), а потом соответсвенно сделать хеш? Буду рад и решению,и подсказкам.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! Вот готовый скрипт,если кому-то понадобится. Единственное,что по ключу name.
    
#!/usr/bin/perl
  use strict;
  use warnings;
  use Getopt::Long;
  
my $names="";
GetOptions ("name=s" => \$names );
open FILE, "<", $names or die $!;
  undef(local $/);
  my $text = <FILE>;
  
close FILE;

my @list = split(//, $text);
my %h;


$h{$_}++ foreach (@list);


foreach (keys %h) {
          $_=$h{$_};
}
     
     
          foreach(sort {$h{$b} <=> $h{$a}} keys %h) {
          print $_,'=',$h{$_},"\n";
}

Comment: foreach (keys %h) {
          $_=$h{$_};
}

этот код лишний, я его использовал для вывода результатов. И тело цикла написано неверно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
my @list = qw(a n о д б д ж д ж ж ж д a);
my %h;

$h{$_}++ foreach (@list);

foreach (keys %h) {
    say "$_=$h{$_}";
}
```

Comment: Ну а как сделать вывод в порядке убывания ты и сам догадаешься. Если не догадаешься - пиши)))